# How to sign text or XML with PFX asking for the private key password. (VS 2005)

Tags: visual-studio-2005, digital-signature

I´m trying to sign some text or XML node using my certificates, installed on Internet Explorer or from filesystem (or some method!)...but I want to ask the user for his certificate password when signing.

If i´m not wrong, I think that I need that password to access the private key and with that key, sign my data....is ok?

Nothing that I read helps me in the part of asking the password or getting the private key.

Some examples or help will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(@"c:\Test.pfx", "test")` you can import certificate with the private key information from the PFX file. The private key can be received by `x509.PrivateKey`.

You can find many examples how to sign XML file. For example http://developers.de/blogs/rolf_nebhuth/archive/2009/05/13/signing-xml-documents.aspx or  http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/257599.aspx.

Comment: is there any example for text files?

Comment: @H.Aqjn: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. My old answer is about the problem with importing PFX files: how to prevent interactive asking for the password of the PFX file.

Comment: Excuse me, I mean Is it possible to sign a txt file instead of signing a xml file with your method?

Comment: @H.Aqjn: Everything is possible, but the problem is where to save the signature. There are standard hos to sign XML file and to save the signature *inside of the same file*. The same exist for EXE/CAT/CAB files, but not with text files. What you ask is very common question about signing on common files. Typically one use additional CAT file, which contains hash values of some files (like the text file) and then one singes the CAT time.